# Get tokens from a String until they are exhausted in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that reads input strings from stdin and get only part of the value from the input.  The input string can have any number of key/value pairs and is in the following format:

```
{"input0":"name:/data/name0.csv",
 "input1":"name:/data/name1.csv",
 ....}
```

So in the above example, I want to get these as the output of my script:

```
/data/name0.csv
/data/name1.csv
.....
```

I think I need two while loops, one needs to keep reading from stdin, the other one needs to extract the values from the input until there is no more.  Can someone let me know how to do the second loop block ?

Comment: If your input is JSON, is there a reason you aren't using a JSON-aware tool such as `jq` to parse it? This will make your script much more robust against formatting changes in the input.

Answer (score 1):

if you have

```
{"input0":"name:/data/name0.csv",
    "input1":"name:/data/name1.csv",
    ....}
```

inside a file `abc.in`, then you can do the following to parse your input with a command called sed:

```
cat abc.in | sed 's/.*"input[0-9]\+":"name:\(\/data\/name[0-9]\+.csv\)".*$/\1/g'
```

it basically lookup the current line with a regular expression and see if it matches one of the form Begining of line then anything"input and  a  number":"name:/data/name and a number.csv"anything and then end of line.
The result is:

```
/data/name1.csv
/data/name2.csv
/data/name3.csv
/data/name4.csv
...
```

Comment: No problem I'm glad it helps :) Is it really what you wanted though?

Answer (score 1):

A simple [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop works here, with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) preprocessing your string into line-oriented content:

```
while read -r value; do
  echo "${value#name:}"
done < <(jq -r '.[]')
```

---

That said, you can actually do the whole thing just in `jq` with no bash at all; the following transforms your given input directly to your desired output (given `jq` 1.5 or newer):

```
jq -r '.[] | sub("name:"; "")'
```

---

If you *really* want to do things the fragile way rather than leveraging a JSON parser, you can do that too:

```
# This is evil: Will fail very badly if input formatting changes
content_re='"name:(.*)"'
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $content_re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

There's still no inner loop required -- just a single loop iterating over lines of input, with the body determining how to process each line.